# Expand rows by column value in Presto

Tags: presto

I have data which has id, number like:

```
id,  number
 1,       5
 2,       3
```

And I would like data to be:

```
id, number
 1,      0
 1,      1
 1,      2
 1,      3
 1,      4
 1,      5 
 2,      0
 2,      1
 2,      2 
 2,      3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  t.id
       ,s.n

from    mytable t 
        cross join unnest(sequence(0,t.number)) s (n)
;
```